# updating certificates from jks to pkcs12 causes build fail

Tags: maven, ssl, jenkins

I had below code in java 8 which is working fine.

```bash
mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME""$JRE_PREFIX"/lib/security && \
        keytool -import -alias Org1Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME"/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt && \
```

I'm trying to upgrade to java 11 with keystore type from jks to pkcs12 format but the jenkins build is failing

```bash
 mkdir -p "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security && \
        keytool -importcert -alias Org1Cert -keystore "$JAVA_HOME"/conf/security/cacerts -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Org1_CA.crt -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

After this change the build is failing with below error -

> Error building classpath. Failed to read artifact descriptor for wp:address-risk-predictor:jar:1.0
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.myorg:myorg.artifact:jar:1.0
> at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
> at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
> at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:263)
> at clojure.tools.deps.extensions.maven$read_descriptor.invokeStatic(maven.clj:115)
> at clojure.tools.deps.extensions.maven$fn__1162.invokeStatic(maven.clj:143)
> at clojure.tools.deps.extensions.maven$fn__1162.invoke(maven.clj:143)
> at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:244)
> at clojure.tools.deps$expand_deps$children_task__771$fn__773$fn__774.invoke(deps.clj:406)
> at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
> at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
> at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
> at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.invokeStatic(core.clj:1990)
> at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1990)
> at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
> at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
> at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
> at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:671)
> at clojure.core$bound_fn_STAR_$fn__5818.doInvoke(core.clj:2020)
> at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
> at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact wp:address-risk-predictor:pom:1.0 from/to libs-release (https://artifactory.myorg/artifactory/libs-release): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:431)
> at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:235)
> at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:212)
> at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
> ... 23 more
> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact wp:address-risk-predictor:pom:1.0 from/to libs-release (https://artifactory.myorg/artifactory/libs-release): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
> at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:401)
> at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder.lambda$wrap$0(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:73)
> at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:669)
> at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:290)
> at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
> at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:408)
> ... 26 more
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:360)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:298)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
> at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
> at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
> at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
> at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:359)
> at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:294)
> at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:72)
> at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:496)
> at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:396)
> ... 31 more
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
> ... 58 more
> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
> at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
> at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
> at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
> ... 64 more

Comment: **The Java 11 cacerts file is at JAVA/lib/security/cacerts.** (Actually any Java 9 up.) The path does not include a `jre/` subdirectory as in Java 8 down, but the `lib` part is NOT changed to `JAVA/conf`. Some other files like `java.security` and the policy jars do move to `conf` but `cacerts` does not. Also there's no point in the `mkdir`; if you have Java that dir already exists, and if you don't have Java trying to set `cacerts` is useless because it can't be used.